# Mathematical optimization, capacitated Vehicle Routing Problem with several capacities.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I'm trying to write down a mathematical formulation for a cVRP using two capacities. In a normal cVRP setting, the capacity and sub-tour elimination constraints are written as

\begin{equation}
d_i \le u_{ik} \le C
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u_{ik} + d_j - C(1-x_{ijk}) \le u_{jk} 
\end{equation}

where $C$ is the capacity, $d_i$ is the demand at location/node $i$, $u_{ik}$ is the cumulative capacity for vehicle $k$ upon servicing location $i$.

The setting I have is a warehouse where pickers, using forklifts, pick items ordered by customers. Each item resides at a certain pick location in the warehouse and each item has a weight and volume. A fork lift has an upper limit in terms of weight (W) and volume (V) it can carry thus we need two constraints. Let $d_i^{w}$ and $d_i^{v}$ be the weight and volume demand at location $i$ respectively, $u_{ik}^{w}$ and $u_{ik}^{v}$ be the cumulative weight and volume of fork lift $k$ carried after picking at location $i$ and $x_{ijk}$ the indicator of travel of fork lift $k$ from location $i$ to $j$, also the decision variable.

How can I formulate the above equations in this case? Splitting the first two equations in two cases is simple enough using $W$ and $V$ instead of $C$, but how to modify the subtour elimination constraints in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also have two versions of the subtour elimination constraints.  They share the $x_{ijk}$ variables, but one will use $u^w$, $d^w$, and $W$, and the other one will use $u^v$, $d^v$, and $V$.  This idea generalizes to any number of resources.

Comment: Thank you! I suppose the way it works is that it chooses the most restrictive of these subtour elimination constraints and bases the subtouring on that?

Comment: Yes, the feasible region is the intersection of the constraints.